# .net Chart x axis value is not displayed under the column

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

For the code below

```
 foreach (LeaveType lvType in statsForBP.LeavesPerType.Keys)
        {
           var series = new Series();
            series.Points.AddXY(lvType.TypeofLeave.ToString(),statsForBP.LeavesPerType[lvType]);
            series.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;

            chart.Series.Add(series);
        }
```

I get the following result.

[image: The x value is off]

Any ideas how to bring the x value directly below?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a DataPoint separately and add a AxisLabel, like this:

```
DataPoint dpValue = new DataPoint();
dpValue.SetValueY(value);
dpValue.AxisLabel = "Label";
```

Comment: No dice. Same exact outcome.